# Which Wi-Fi technology do "Tuya" smart plugs use to get configured and join the Wi-Fi network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Which Wi-Fi technology is being used in smart plugs like the ones from Chinese vendor "Tuya", where in order to register a new device to your Wi-Fi network through what's called quick connect mode, you just use your smartphone which is already in your Wi-Fi network and follow these steps:

1. Power on the smart plug device.
2. Through their app you select the wifi network name and enter the password.
3. Then the app searches and connects directly to the device and registers it to your Wi-Fi network.

Note: I didn't press any WPS button, I didn't scan any QR codes, I didn't connect to the device's access point. I did nothing; I just told the app which Wi-Fi network.

What is this Wi-Fi technology, is it Wi-Fi Easy Connect or what?

Comment: It could be completely proprietary. Through the app, you gave it the name and password of the Wi-Fi network you wanted it to join. So it's the same as when a friend comes over and you tell them the name and Wi-Fi password of your network, and they enter it on their laptop or smartphone, and it joins the network as usual.

Comment: @Spiff how the app communicates with the device, no Bluetooth nor wifi connection?

Comment: who says it has no Wi-Fi connection? The smarphone app may be using an Android or iOS API that lets it switch Wi-Fi networks temporarily to configure the device. It's possible it could be using Wi-Fi Direct or Wi-Fi Aware to make the connection, but it could be that the device is publishing an SSID in AP mode and you just didn't realize it because the app was automatically handling searching for the Tuya-proprietary SSID and switching to it for a brief moment while it sends the device the SSID and password of the network it needs to join.

Comment: @spiff, Could the smart phone allow a switch to another AP with the  user permission, at least in IOS? I already tested the device connection with ios and it was the same behaviour like in Android by the way.

Comment: Wifi direct is blocked by ios by the way

Answer (score 1):

Data is encoded in the length of UDP broadcast packets. The length is visible (the same as unencrypyted packets). Source:  https://www.elttam.com/blog/ez-mode-pairing/